# Need to understand proof - there are at most finitely many simple groups with a proper subgroup of index less-than-or-equal to integer n.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ is a finite, simple group with proper subgroup $H$ with index $m < n$, then there is a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_m$, where the kernel is a subgroup of $H$. (How do we know this exists?)

We know $ker=\langle 1\rangle$ and $G$ is isomorphic to the image of this map. (How do we know this?)

Since $S_n$ is finite,then there are only finitely many of such groups.

Answer (score 4):

$G$ acts on the cosets of $H$, i.e. the set $\Omega=\{H\cdot g\mid g\in G\}$ by right multiplication. The kernel of this action is the intersection of all subgroups of the form $H^g$ for $g\in G$ (hint : which elements fix $H\cdot g$?) which is called the core of $H$. This intersection is a subgroup of $G$, and in fact it is the kernel of the map defined by the action of $G$ on $\Omega$.

Since $G$ is simple, this kernel must be trivial. Using the first isomorphism theorem, we see that $G$ is isomorphic to its image under this map. As you said, there are only finitely many subgroups of $S_n$.